# Provide me samples on Spring Security OAuth2.0 Jdbc token store for potgresql

Tags: postgresql, spring-security-oauth2

Im new to Spring Security OAuth2. Please provide me samples on Spring Security OAuth2 Jdbc token store for PostgreSQL.Give samples for above requirement to understand the Spring Security OAuth2 Jdbc token store.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can find DB schema [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql).
To add support to the code you can create bean:

```
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }
```

And for PostgreSQL use BYTEA type instead of LONGVARBINARY